# Sampling from a population

Tags: probability

I have a very basic propability question:

There are 200 socks in my basket. 25 are white, the rest are black. If I pick 10 socks, what's the probability of picking 3 white ones?

I tried to calculate as follows:

P_3 = [25/200 * 24/199 * 23/198] * [175/197 * 174/196 * 173/195 * 172/194 * 171/193 * 170/192 * 169/191]

However, when I create all P_{0-10} and sum them up I don't get a overall probability of 1. So I must be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) comes to the rescue here.

The answer follows immediately:

$$\frac{\binom{25}{3} * \binom{175}{7}}{\binom{200}{10}}$$